# What is the name of this colour scheme element?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

I have an annoying problem with Visual Studio highlighting. I installed my favourite colourscheme ([zenburn 2010](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/zenburn-2010)), and I have found that when I'm in debug mode, this will happen when my application is paused:

[image]

I have run through the hundred or so colours in the settings window, but I am unable to locate the setting that will affect this background colour. It's not exactly a show-stopper, but I'd still really like to know how to solve this.

I have resharper installed in case that affects anything. I can't see how it would though.

Comment: If you are debugging a 64-bit program then you probably should mention that.

Comment: The platform is "Any CPU" but this machine is a 64-bit box. I have no idea how this could affect my IDE's code highlighting.

Comment: When on a 64-bit machine, I've found that the "Any CPU" will cause your debug code to be uneditable with the error "`Changes to 64-bit applications are not allowed.`" If you specify "x86" you can edit the code during breakpoints, etc. As for the highlight color, if it isn't "Selected Text" I'm not sure what else it could be. Try disabling Resharper (Tools > Options > Resharper > Suspend) temporarily to see if it's (partially) responsible.

Comment: @JYelton, @Hans: No.  This highlights any `catch` block around the active statement.  I'm not sure what it's called, though.

Comment: If I remember right it is _Current Statement_

Answer (score 1):

I think you want either the **Collapsible Region** element, or the **Selected Text** element

Answer (score 1):

Changing the background color of the **Read-Only Region** element solved the issue for me. (See [this article](http://catchblock.com/blog/post/2012/01/12/Changing-the-background-color-of-catch-block-when-debugging-in-Visual-Studio.aspx) for more detail.)

Comment: The linked page no longer exists.  Here's an archived copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20140727145812/http://catchblock.com/blog/post/2012/01/12/Changing-the-background-color-of-catch-block-when-debugging-in-Visual-Studio.aspx